# ターミナルでコマンド入力後にエンターを押しても、繰り返し ”>" のみが表示されてしまう

Tags: rubygems, shell

初学者です。ターミナルでコマンドを入力した後、エンターを押すと">"のみが出てきて、何度エンターを押しても">"のみで改行されていきます。

これはどういった状態なのでしょうか。

Comment: 「ターミナルでコマンドを入力した」との事ですが、どのようなコマンドを入力したのでしょうか？　コマンドが異なると、動作も異なります。『どんなコマンドを入力したのか』が判らないと、この質問に答えられません。

Comment: @にゃーちゃん さん、良い感じの言い方が分からなければ、作業開始からの状況が映っているターミナルのスクリーンショットを投稿に添付して頂けると伝わりやすいかもしれません。質問文下の「編集」を押すと出てくる編集画面からファイルを添付できますのでお試しください。

Comment: 返信遅くなってしまいました。わけも分からず適当に入力していたため当時の状況も何も覚えていないのですが、おそらく何かのgemを入れようとしていたときだったと思います。したにあるtake88様の回答がおそらく正解だと思います。私自身「何がわからないのかわからない。」状態であるためこういった歯切れの悪いコメントになってしまい申し訳ありません。

Answer (score 3):

セカンダリプロンプトが表示されてると思います。
コマンド入力が完了しておらず 入力待ちの状態です。
Ctrl-C （Ctrlを押しながらC）を押すことで 入力がキャンセルされて元の状態に戻ると思います。

クォートを閉じ忘れると そういう状態になるので
入力した コマンドに間違いがないか 確認してみてください

例）

```
$ echo "hello world  ← クォートを閉じ忘れたままEnterを押した状態
>                    ← クォートが閉じてないので 入力まちの状態
>
> "                  ← クォートを閉じるとコマンドが実行される
hello world
```